# How to revert the changes from one radioButton when another is clicked C#

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have two Radio Buttons. One adds a value of 1 and the other adds a value of 11 to the final total. I have them both grouped in a panel. When I select one of the buttons it add the value correctly, but when I then select the other radio button after i have selected the first one it adds that new value onto the final total without ignoring the first radio button selection. Is there a simple line of code to just ignore the first selection?

Comment: could you please post your code for this

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Eh, *subtract* `1` or `11` (depending on radio button) from the total before  adding?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko this would lead to incorrect states on the first Click. but yeah, sth. like that.

Comment: @ Dimitry: will give wrong output on first click

Comment: 1. Store total without changes. 2. Determine changes by selected radio button. 3. changedTotal = total + changes;

Comment: If you are working in `CheckedChanged` Event then, you need to check `if ( radioButton.Checked)` because it fires on check and uncheck as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use like the following, i will give more clarified output if you post the code which you are using.

```
  double total = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text);
  //On Radiobutton1's click
  if(radio1.Checked)  
  txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total + 1);
  //On Radiobutton2's click
  if (radio2.Checked)  
  txtTotal.Text =Convert.ToString( total + 11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a method to find the final total and add the value 1 or 11 from that method. Something like:

```
public void final()
{
    if(radiobtn1.Checked)
        finalTotal=grandTotal+1;
    else if(radiobtn2.Checked)
        finalTotal=grandTotal+11;
}
```

Or you can do it from the click event of those radiobuttons. This will find the final total each time. If you have more calculations to do, I would recommend using a separate method as shown above.

**EDIT:**

As per your code:

```
int playerCardFinalTotal = 0;
int pcFinalTotal = 0;

private void btnChangeValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (rdbOne.Checked)
    {
        pcFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + 1;
    }
    else if (rdbEleven.Checked)
    {
        pcFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + 11;
    }
}
```

**Changes:**

1. You can use `.Checked` itself instead of `==true` and `!rdbOne.Checked` instead of `==false` (just a tip)
2. Use another variable `pcFinalTotal` for storing the Total Value. It will be reset to the correct value each time you click any of those radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without knowing anything about application (web/desktop based) and code. But I see two options

- Retain original value somewhere and on radio button selection add to original value to get total
- Subtract value for other radio button and then add value for current selection to get total

Answer (score 0):

You could add the added value to a variable which you initialize to 0 (zero).

Whenever you click a radiobutton, subtract the value of the variable from the value you add to the final total.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating a change button the just subtracts the value of the one selected.

```
private void btnChangeValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            

    if (rdbOne.Checked == true)
    {
        playerTallyTotals(-1);
        rdbOne.Checked = false;
        pnlValues.Enabled = true;
    }

    else if (rdbEleven.Checked == true)
    {
        playerTallyTotals(-11);
        rdbEleven.Checked = false;
        pnlValues.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

It gets passed to:

```
int playerCardFinalTotal = 0;
private void playerTallyTotals(int playerCardTotalx)
{            
    playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + playerCardTotalx;
}
```

Comment: When i select 1 it adds the 1 correctly to the final total, but when i click the change button it deducts 10 and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

always preserve the original value:

```
int total = someValue;
int finalTotal;
private void radioEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioOne.Checked)
    {
        finalTotal = total + 1;
    }
    if(radioTwo.Checked)
    {
        finalTotal = total + 11;
    }
}
```

when you submit your result, you will use the final value.